# Chrome Webdriver Refresh does not respond since Chrome 106

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Since I have upgraded to Chrome 106 (and now to 107) the driver manages to open the URL at the first time but after some timeout (?) or other criteria, the driver.refresh() does not return (i.e. no resposne).
The way it looks to me, if the Refresh occurs within seconds since the initial open, then the refresh succeeds.
Yet, if longer interval has elapsed since the initial open, then the refresh() does not complete.
Code is in Python.

Before version 106 this seemed to work well

Does anyone experience similar behaviour? Any idea how to fix that?

```
#Code to create the driver:
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'...  \chromedriver', options=chrome_options)`

#Then, the attempt to refresh: 
    driver.refresh()
```

Expecting the webpage to refresh

Comment: I have tried to apply driver.get instead of the driver.refresh() call and it seems that the driver has been disconnected- i.e. no response as well. Is there any timeout setting that would cause the webdriver to disconnect and stop listening to the driver commands? Maybe it has to do with some generic Chrome setting?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it on google colab? try this

```
import sys sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') 
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

if your work does not depend much on it, just use earlier versions where it used to work.

if not, try the following:
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'r')

Comment: I can try that, but since the driver.get also stop responding, I fear that the whole driver gets disconnected. Trying to re-install chromdriver 105 is not an option since then Chrome refuses to open all together (I think it requires a match between the installed Chrom browser version and the Chromedriver version)

Comment: Can you do it on google colab?

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)

Comment: Hi Rony- so the code as is does not run. Syntax issue on the 1st line. I split it and added !pip install selenium but still does not work- under the /usr/lib I still do not see the chromium-browser folder. Yet, I can try adding the chrome options to my code but those seem to be more related to the dev environment - so not really applicable to my code (running out of COLAB)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).